# listout all the files of a folder to the right side of a container using vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, tree

In my application, i have list of folders and each containing some files. I have to display those files while choosing particular folder. Those folder will be in left side.While selecting that folder, files will be listed out in right side.

my json is like this:

```
folders : [
        {id: 0, name: 'Animals', files:['cat.jpg','dog.jpg']},
        {id: 1, name: 'Birds',files:['crow.jpg','sparrow.jpg']},
        {id: 2, name: 'Area',files:['desert.jpg','river.jpg']}
    ]
```

So if i choose 'Animals' folder then two files will be listed out in right side.

Like these :

[image: folder file design]

I am new to vuejs. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list the folders on the left side and a variable `files` on the right side that would be updated by those of the clicked folder each time:

```js
new Vue({
     el: '#app',
     data(){
          return{
               folders : [
                    {id: 0, name: 'Animals', files:['cat.jpg','dog.jpg']},
                    {id: 1, name: 'Birds',files:['crow.jpg','sparrow.jpg']},
                    {id: 2, name: 'Area',files:['desert.jpg','river.jpg']}
               ],
               files: []
          }
     },
     methods:{
          showFiles(id){
               let f = (this.folders).filter(f=>{return f.id==id})[0];
               this.files = f.files;
          }
     }
});
```

```css
.folders {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
.files {
    margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
     <div class="folders">
          <ul>
               <li v-for="(folder,index) in folders" :key="index">
                    <a @click="showFiles(folder.id)">{{folder.name}}</a>
               </li>
          </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="files">
          <ul>
               <li v-for="(file,index) in files" :key="index">
                    {{file}}
               </li>
          </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Majed... I need help on this. The same thing above i have to do with treeview. Where some folder is having files on their child node. I have to display those files like you suggested earlier for normal view. I have opened one more question for this ..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63330877/filter-files-based-on-folder-selection-in-element-ui-tree-with-vue