# filter files based on folder selection in element ui tree with vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, treeview, element-ui

I am using element ui treeview to display folders. There are some files for each folder or their child folder. I have to list out those files based on folder selection. I can filter out those in normal list. But, i am not able to do that using element ui tree view. Please suggest me how to do that for tree node. Here is the sample data:

```
   data: [{
      id: 1,
      label: 'Level one 1',
      type: 'folder',
      children: [{
        id: 4,
        label: 'Level two 1-1',
        type: 'folder',
        children: [
          { id: 9, label: 'Level three 1-1-1', type: 'file'}, 
          { id: 10, label: 'Level three 1-1-2', type: 'file' }]
      }]
    }, {
      id: 2,
      label: 'Level one 2',
      type: 'folder',
      children: [
        { id: 5, label: 'Level two 2-1', type: 'file'}, 
        { id: 6, label: 'Level two 2-2', type: 'file'}]
    }, {
      id: 3,
      label: 'Level one 3',
      type: 'folder',
      children: [
        { id: 7, label: 'Level two 3-1', type: 'file'}, 
        { id: 8, label: 'Level two 3-2', type: 'file'}]
    }]
```

**Here is my tree's code snippet :**

```
<el-row style="background: #f2f2f2">
                  <el-col :span="6">
                   <div class="folder-content">
                     <el-tree
                         node-key="id"
                         :data="data"
                         accordion
                         @node-click="nodeclicked"
                         ref="tree"
                         style="background: #f2f2f2"
                         highlight-current
                         >
                         <span class="custom-tree-node" slot-scope="{ node, data }">
                             <span class="icon-folder" v-if="data.type === 'folder'">
                              <i class="el-icon-folder" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                              <span class="icon-folder_text" >{{ data.name }}</span>
                             </span>
                         </span>
                     </el-tree>
                   </div>
                 </el-col>
                 <el-col :span="12"><div class="entry-content">
                  <ul>
                      <li aria-expanded="false" v-for="(file,index) in files" :key="index">
                           <span class="folder__list"><input type="checkbox" :id= "file" :value="file">
                           <i class="el-icon-document" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                          <span class="folder__name">{{file.name}}</span></span>
                     </li>
                 </ul>
                   </div></el-col>
                 <el-col :span="6"><div class="preview_content"></div></el-col>
               </el-row>
```

how to list out those files while traversing first folder and it's child node in that tree? Please suggest me on this. I want to display like this below:
[image: simple File browsing]

If i choose first folder or it's children. Then files associated with this display in a list like '**File Browsing**'

Answer (score 1):

When you get the `node` from the tree you could access the children (node provided by the method doesn't contain any child data), but if you want display the files in a different container and not in the tree you probably search with javascript in the data yourself.

```js
var Main = {
    methods: {
      nodeclicked(node) {
        console.log(this.$refs.tree.getNode(node.id).data.children)
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        data: [{
          id: 1,
          label: 'Level one 1',
          type: 'folder',
          children: [{
            id: 4,
            label: 'Level two 1-1',
            type: 'folder',
            children: [
              { id: 9, label: 'Level three 1-1-1', type: 'file'}, 
              { id: 10, label: 'Level three 1-1-2', type: 'file' }]
          }]
        }, {
          id: 2,
          label: 'Level one 2',
          type: 'folder',
          children: [
            { id: 5, label: 'Level two 2-1', type: 'file'}, 
            { id: 6, label: 'Level two 2-2', type: 'file'}]
        }, {
          id: 3,
          label: 'Level one 3',
          type: 'folder',
          children: [
            { id: 7, label: 'Level two 3-1', type: 'file'}, 
            { id: 8, label: 'Level two 3-2', type: 'file'}]
        }],
        defaultProps: {
          children: 'children',
          label: 'label'
        }
      }
    }
  };
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.13.2/lib/theme-chalk/index.css");
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.13.2/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <el-tree
    node-key="id"
    :data="data"
    :props="defaultProps"
    accordion
    @node-click="nodeclicked"
    ref="tree">
    <span class="custom-tree-node" slot-scope="{ node, data }">
      <span class="icon-folder">
        <i v-if="data.type === 'folder'" class="el-icon-folder"></i>
        <i v-else-if="data.type === 'file'" class="el-icon-document"></i>
        <span class="icon-folder_text">{{ data.label }}</span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </el-tree>
</div>
```

Comment: I have updated my code as you suggest. I am pushing those objects to other array and using v-for to iterate those. problem is 1. tree is expanded by default because of traversing to children node.  How to prevent that if children is file not folder?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but you could check if there are any child elements or check if the current node is from the type `file` or `folder`.

Comment: I want to do simple file browser. If any folder is having files or doc in their children. So while clicking the that root folder node those files or docs will be displayed in some list like browsing a file... I am giving the image.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Main = {
  data() {
    return {
      data: [{
          id: 1,
          name: 'folder 1',
          type: 'folder',
          children: [{
            id: 4,
            name: 'subFiles 1-1',
            type: 'folder',
            children: []
          }, {
            id: 11,
            name: 'files 1-1',
            type: 'file'
          }, {
            id: 12,
            name: 'files 1-2',
            type: 'file'
          }]
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'folder 2',
          type: 'folder',
          children: []
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'folder 3',
          type: 'folder',
          children: []
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleNodeClick() {}
  }
}
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.13.0/lib/theme-chalk/index.css");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.13.0/lib/index.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <el-tree :data="data" accordion @node-click="handleNodeClick">
    <span class="custom-tree-node" slot-scope="{ node, data }">
                                 <span class="icon-folder">
                                  <i v-if="data.type === 'folder'" class="el-icon-folder" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                   <i v-else-if="data.type === 'file'" class="el-icon-document" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                  <span class="icon-folder_text">{{ data.name }}</span>
    </span>
    </span>
  </el-tree>
</div>
```

ElementUI specifies the data structure of `data`, so the subtree node are unified push in `children` property, and then use the `type` property to distinguish whether it is a `folder` or a `file`.

Comment: Thanks for valuable answer. But, there are array of files in root folder or child folder. I have to display files based on selected nodes. If i click subfiles 1-1 child node then files for this folder will display in a list.  It is like 'File explorer/ browser'. I just need filter part while folder change

Comment: No but your process is correct only. Just want to display those files in different place not in default expanded. I am updating the code because i am using el-row and el-col